# Importing raster data automatically to GeoServer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgis-raster

I'mtrying to make an automatic raster data import to GeoServer for later use in an OpenLayers web application in which i need to add raster files frequently, so I added Image Mosaic JDBC Plugin and configured it following [this tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html#imagemosaicjdbc-install),
but I end up with this error :

```
java -jar C:/"Program Files (x86)"/"GeoServer 2.15.0"/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-21.2.jar ddl -config /  C:/"Program Files (x86)"/"GeoServer 2.15.0"/data_dir/coverages/osm.postgis.xml -spatialTNPrefix ne_raster -pyramids 6 -statementDelim ";" -srs 4326 -targetDir ne_raster_sqlscripts
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Aug 18, 2019 9:23:58 PM org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.DDLGenerator start
INFO:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Config.readFrom(Config.java:140)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.DDLGenerator.start(DDLGenerator.java:113)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.Toolbox.main(Toolbox.java:47)
```

I also tried to follow [this tuto](https://github.com/lcalisto/workshop-postgis-raster/blob/master/doc/geoserver.md)
using GeoServer 2.15 and PGRaster 2.15 but still getting errors when save

```
Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them:
Failed to create reader from file:data/trees.pgraster.xml and hints 
Hints:
EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@a39986[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] 
REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@1a376a4 System 
defaults: FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@17186db 
FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory 
TILE_ENCODING = null 
LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true 
STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl 
FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true 
COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 
FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl
```

I don't know if there's something I missed or those plugins are just buggy.

**trees.pgraster.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
      <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
      <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.pgraster.xml.inc">
]>
<config version="1.0">
      <coverageName name="oek"/>
      <coordsys name="EPSG:3763"/> tried 4326 also 
      <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
      <axisOrder ignore="false"/>
      &mapping;
      &connect;
</config>`

**connect.pgraster.xml.inc**

`<connect>
  <!-- value DBCP or JNDI -->
  <dstype value="DBCP"/>
  <!--   <jndiReferenceName value=""/>  -->
  <username value="postgres" />
  <password value="geoinfo" />
  <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ArbresZones" />
  <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <maxActive value="500"/>
  <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>`

**mapping.pgraster.xml.inc**

`<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
 <mapping>
      <masterTable name="mosaic" >
              <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
              <maxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
              <maxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
              <minXAttribute name="minX"/>
              <minYAttribute name="minY"/>
              <resXAttribute name="resX"/>
              <resYAttribute name="resY"/>
              <tileTableNameAtribute name="tiletable" />
      </masterTable>
      <tileTable>
              <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
      </tileTable>
</mapping>`

Comment: the error seems to be saying that `data/trees.pgraster.xml` is invalid at line 1. Can you add that file to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: i added the trees.pgraster.xml fil and the 2 xml.inc other files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoServer REST API is your best option build a form for upload data and post to Geo server build WMS and WMTS

Comment: REST API in cmd windows did the work trying to make it work on ajax
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332581/curl-rest-api-to-ajax