# curl REST API to AJAX

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, ajax, cors, curl

I'm trying to make a web application that is able to :

1) Upload raster data to GeoServer so when I use this command on cmd it works

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -v -XPUT -H "Content-type: image/tiff" --data-binary @"C:\Path\odm_orthophoto.tif"  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/raster_data/coveragestores/int_dec/file.geotiff
```

but on AJAX it doesn't work, giving me error 401 unauthorized here's my code

```
$.ajax({    
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy");
            },
             url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/raster_data/coveragestores/int_decc/file.geotiff",
             contentType: "image/tiff",
             method : 'PUT',
             xhrFields:{
                  withCredentials: true
             },
             data : '--data-binary @"C:/Path/odm_orthophoto.tif"' ,
             success : function(data){
                  console.log(data);
             },
             error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
                 alert(status+" "+exception);
             }
        });
```

I also tried to use

```
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic' + 'admin:geoserver'
  }
```

but still getting the same error. I enabled CORS in `web.xml` in `WEB-INF` GeoServer folder, without the jetty.jar file like said here `https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210109/enabling-cors-in-geoserver-jetty` because adding it give me error 503 when opening geoserver.

2) Read layer's name from the coverage store also with REST API it works on Windows with this command

`curl -u admin:geoserver -XGET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/raster_data/coveragestores/int_dec/coverages.json`

My JavaScript code is :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/raster_data/coveragestores/int_dec/coverages.json",
    type: 'GET',  
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
        },
    error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
        alert(status+" "+exception);
    }
});
```

but I get this error

> unexpected token: ':'

When I add

```
xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
}
```

to AJAX parameters I get the same error as 1) 401 unauthorized , which should eliminate CORS problem according to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953965/uncaught-syntaxerror-and-cors-error-using-ajax-with-jsonp/38956911#38956911` using `json` as `datatype` returns the same error

I'm using GeoServer 2.15 and JRE 8u221 32bits

**UPDATE :**

using `withCredentials: true` , worked for getting json list but not for the `PUT` method i get know `HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error`
here's the output of my curl command i think i need to change url to `http:/localhost:8080` but i don't know what to do with the `/geoserver/rest/workspaces/raster_data/coveragestores/int_decc/file.geotiff`
[image]

Comment: Geoserver is expecting basic authentication, so you may need to set with credentials to true

Comment: your solution worked fine for 2) i'm able to get json output and read it in JS , but 1) i'm getting  `500 Server Error` i added the output of curl request from the cmd don't know if it can help, Thanks

Comment: i ended using php's exec since it can run windows commands and it works just fine.